# Two-column layout with divs of the same class... and a space in between

Tags: css, html, css-float, multiple-columns

There are two `<div>` elements, each with the same class. It is easy to make them into a two-column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/nbzHA/3/

**So here's the catch:**

How do you add a whitespace between them?

It would be easy to make two separate classes, and float them either way. 
Or add a class to one and use margins: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/sZehH/1/

But what if they're in the same class/no class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `class` on the first div is the best browser compatibility solution, then add your style for this class.

There are things I noticed with your fiddle which make it complex to have solution based on your comments to niels. You have a `section` tag in your fiddle which will render in a browser supporting an html5. But you want to have a compatibility with IE7 and IE6?

There are ways for IE7, below is one of those:

```
.section div+div {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

This solution use the [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) which added a margin-left on the second div. And also, instead of `section` tag I use a <>div with `class=section` for the benefits of browser that don't support `section`.

For `IE6`, adding a class on one of the two <>div is the only solution I know.

Comment: Thanks Ace! You're right. But there are JS solutions to make new HTML5 tags compatible in older browsers. But from what I understand, that won't work with JS turned off?

Comment: Even if there are JS solutions to make new HTML5 tags compatible with older browsers it will not give you a guarantee that it will work as you expected. It's better if you have an alternative tag to support the older browser. And yes, the JS solution will not work if JS is turned off.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I thought that the JS solutions to convert HTML5 tags were pretty solid. What kind of problems are there? So, alternatively, do you mean using `<div class="section">` instead of `<section>` and so on? But then that's no longer HTML5 in this sense :(

Comment: It would depends on your requirements, if the JS solution can render `<section>` correctly then go ahead and use it. I'm not too familiar with JS solution, it's my assumption that some HTML5 tags like `<video>, <audio>, <canvas>` could have some issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo class such as `:nth-child(n)` or `:first-child`

`section div:nth-child(1) {
margin-right: 10%;
}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yup, but IE doesn't support that :(

Comment: Did you try `:first-child` as well? According to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) it _almost_ works in IE8 (whatever that means)...

Comment: Thanks Niels, I'm going for IE6 and IE7 compatibility as well (with simple & fun things like this at least). I'm trying to think up a `position:` solution...

Comment: I am out of ideas, I think you have to add a separate class :(

Comment: Thanks for your help! Think so too :(

But I'll wait for some other replies. If nobody will reply, I'll mark your post as the solution :)